# How to change mouse speed when acceleration is 0?

Tags: mouse

It looks like in mouse preferences "tracking speed" changes acceleration of the mouse. How can I set acceleration to 0 and adjust speed of the mouse?

Comment: @Robuust, I tried to change settings in mouse preferences. I tried to google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SmoothMouse](http://smoothmouse.com):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have two systems -- G5 running Tiger 10.4.11 and Intel Macbook 2009 running Mavericks 10.9.2.  I do graphic work on both using mouse.  Neither one offers a separate control for acceleration.  Mouse speed control only, so acceleration appears defaulted to 0.  There is a discussion of this issue at :
http://triq.net/articles/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x

Comment: This is not true. First, you can compare the distances your mouse travels on the table when you move it slowly from one edge of your screen to another and when you move it quickly. For me they are different by factor of 4 (And I hate it). Second, you can check the acceleration value with 'defaults read .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling', it is not zero and depends on so called "tracking speed".